# discoverAndAddAccounts or getLoginAccounts when refreshing account

Tags: java, intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I'm using the same AggCatService throughout the examples below. I'm using the Java SDK.

1. The first time a new institution is added by a user in my application, I call discoverAndAddAccounts to add the credentials to the intuit server. Do I also need to do getLoginAccounts for each account to refresh the account or is getAccountTransactions enough?
2. Later, when I'd like to get the fresh information from the accounts added, should I then call discoverAndAddAccounts again or should I only do getLoginAccounts and getAccountTransactions for each account?
3. If I call discoverAndAddAccounts again on refresh, will I then add duplicate credentials information to the Intuit servers or will Intuit know the credentials is already added?

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1| To get refreshed info, you should call UpdateInstituitionLogin with refresh flag set as true immediately after DiscoverAndAddAccounts API call.

Ref- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0075_updateinstitutionlogin#Update_Institution_Login

2| After getting refreshed information, you can directly call GetAccount, getAccountTransactions APIs.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0035_getaccount

3| Ideally it should add the delta. If it doesn't then you can do it programmatically by comparing existing accountIds against the same of API response.
I didn't test it against any real FI. I used CC_Bank but it always returns a static list of accounts.
 - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/testing_calls_to_the_api

I can confirm the behavior and update this post.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Are you sure you mean UpdateInstitutionLogin? The doc says "This is a call that would be made only if the end-user has changed their password..." I don't want to update any password, all I want is the refreshed transaction for this credential.

Comment: 2. My point is that this may happen a day after 1 is done. When I want the refreshed transaction information for all accounts, should I then do getLoginAccounts or discoverAndAddAccounts?

Comment: Yes. You can use UpdateInstitutionLogin(with refresh flag set to true) to get refreshed data. It will trigger an explicit refresh request to actual FI. 

After making a successful call to UpdateInstitutionLogin, you can call getAccounts and getAccountTransaction.

Comment: If you call DnA API twice, in the second time duplicate accounts will be added in your app. This is a bug. You need to add only new accounts programmatically(by cross checking). Thanks